# Creating a maven webapp generates error

Tags: eclipse, maven, web-applications, archetypes

I am using eclipse kepler and I tried to create webapp with maven.
File->new->Maven project. then I chose webapp archetype and finished. But it says,

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

I have good internet connection. Also, intellij idea builds a maven webapp. How can get this problem resolved.

Comment: Seems maven embbedded in eclipse is not able to download dependencies, do you use a proxy to connect to the web?

Comment: No. I don't use any proxies.

Comment: First check your build on command line. `mvn clean package`..

Answer (score 0):

This may be because apache is not configured in your targeted run 
time.
Right Click on the project->Properties->Targeted Run Times->Select Apache